# Cost of a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When 'Explain' is used along with the select statement in PostgreSQL, it gives the query plan as shown below

```
Seq Scan on employee  (cost=0.00..12.13 rows=1 width=438)
  Filter: ((lastname)::text = 'John'::text)
```

I couldn't understand what does '0.00..12.13' mean? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6):

First number is startup cost. Second is estimated total cost.

According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/using-explain.html), the costs are measured in arbitrary units determined by the planner's cost parameters. Traditional practice is to measure the costs in units of disk page fetches; that is, seq_page_cost is conventionally set to 1.0 and the other cost parameters are set relative to that.